# Kinvey vs StorageRoom vs Parse other BaaS

Tags: ios, content-management-system, cloud, backend

I'm an iOS dev and I don't have heavy knowledge of web world, most of the time I develop an app I need to interface with a backends. Fortunately I found that there are a plenty of BaaS / CMS on the cloud that really reduce the time to market to implement such services.
Now I'm using StorageRoom (more CMS), I'm pretty happy about it. 
 It has various good features but it lack something else. 
GOOD

- REST API are really simple and you can implement your own REST interface on mobile site. this is important because I trust only in one download manager, the MKNetworkKit, IMHO is the only one well studied and I don't want to digg into there frameworks and try to understand how they manages connections
- You can create different user to edit and make data entry the CMS (but this feature will need more flexibility, actually it shows all collections even if the user have not permissions to CRUD them)
- Webhooks makes very easy and flexible the connection with other services such as PUSH etc
- Low Price
- Quite abstract services so they're really really flexible

MISSING

- Custom business logic
- Advanced editor features
- A sort of social connection/login to create social applications faster
- An integrated service for Push and Passkit
- Since very abstract I'd like to see more facilities for collection management and social login

Can someone that uses Kinvey tell me if it has all the good features of Storageroom and the missing features and share his/her experience with that BaaS or another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am on the development team at Kinvey so this is largely biased towards what I have intimate knowledge on.

Responses to the Good section:

- Kinvey provides native libraries for development. This means you don't need to learn the network layer, manage security on the device side and worry about offline/cache support. We do our best to abstract all that away and make things easier.
- We have a collaboration feature which allows multiple people to administer your app. Currently it gives complete access to work with anything on your app. On the upside you can use the master-secret to have full administration features if you wanted to build out a custom editing interface.
- Push support is baked into our system, you can push to iOS and Android relatively easy.
- Our pricing model is success based pricing, you only pay when you actually hit load. Development is always free.
- We do our best to abstract as many problems away from you to make development as easy as possible.

Responses to the Missing section:

- Kinvey provides custom business logic out of the box, as should most reasonable BaaS solutions.
- As mentioned above, we don't provide a CMS interface for editing, but that does not prevent you from being able to roll your own using the master-secret.
- Kinvey provides social network login out of the box, along with most of the other BaaS companies.
- Kinvey does not integrate directly with Passkit.

Comment: Thanks Ryan that's an important answer for me. The fact you can't have different role access into the collaborative feature it's kind of pity (hope this is the polite term). It's very useful, imagine that right after you create collections and test everything it could be your client to make data entries in an easy way, without messing around. I do understand that you I can make my custom editing interface. Grazie, Andrea